# How to insert string to DATE column and TIME column from Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to insert string '2020-04-16' to DATE type column,  and string type '12:00' to TIME type column from Ecto. DB is MySQL.

Please give me advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it correct way or not.

```
    {:ok, game_date} = Date.from_iso8601("2020-04-16")
    {:ok, game_time} = Time.from_iso8601("12:00:00")
```

It worked.